# How to save the value of Listbox in the database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

i m developing my project in asp.net MVC-3.

In these in one module i created a view for creation of team. 
In that there is one dropdown list of Project name.
and a listbox(ListBox-1) to display the members of the selected project from dropdownlist.
and there is another listbox(ListBox-2) to transfer/select the selected or all records(member's names) in it.
which is done perfectly using javascript.

I have to save all the data in database of that form.
in that  i have to save the list of team members which are displayed in 2nd listbox(ListBox-2) in the database.  And these my question that How to fetch the data of that listbox(ListBox-2) and save it in the database field?

Below is my create team view...
[image]

In this form 1st dropdown list displays the project names
And there are two Listbox below the Dropdownlist which are used to display the member names of the project

view code of the listbox is as below..

```
Dropdownlist for Project
  <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.availableproject, new SelectList(ViewBag.Projects as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "project_id", "project_name"),"Select Project", new { id = "ddlCars" })   %> 


code of listbox.
 <div class="ddlModels" style="float:left; ">
                              <%--  <%: Html.ListBox("projectmembers_id") %>  --%>
                                 <%: Html.ListBoxFor(Models => Models.availableuser, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "user_id", "user_login_name"),
                             new { id = "ddlModels2" }) %>


                            </div>

                            <div style="display:inline; float:left; margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px; margin-top:10px;">
                                <input type="button" name="add" id="alladd"  onclick="CopyListsall();" value=">>" style="width:27px; height:15px; font-size:8px; color:#56a1d6;"/><br />
                                <input type="button" name="add" id="add" onclick="CopyLists();"value=">" style="width:27px; height:15px; font-size:8px; color:#56a1d6;"/><br /><br />
                                <input type="button" name="remove" id="allremove"  onclick="RemoveListsall();" value="<<" style="width:27px; height:15px; font-size:8px; color:#56a1d6;" /><br />                
                                <input type="button" name="remove" id="remove"  onclick="RemoveLists();"  value="<" style="width:27px; height:15px; font-size:8px; color:#56a1d6;" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="ddlModels" style="float:left;">
                             <%: Html.ListBoxFor(Models => Models.availableuser, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "user_id", "user_login_name"),
                             new { id = "ddlModels1" }) %>
                             <%-- <%: Html.ListBox("projectmembers_id") %>--%>
                            </div>
```

code of the model (.cs file)

```
namespace ProjectManagementSystem.Models
{
    public class TeamCreate
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Empty Not Allow")]
        public int team_id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Empty Not Allow")]
        [DisplayName("Team Name")]
        public string team_name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Empty Not Allow")]
        public int project_id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Empty Not Allow")]
        public string project_name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Empty Not Allow")]
        public int projectmembers_id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Empty Not Allow")]
        public int projectmemberuser_id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Empty Not Allow")]
        public int user_id { get; set; }


        public int SerialNumber { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Empty Not Allow")]
        [DisplayName("Team Leader")]
        public string user_real_name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Empty Not Allow")]
        public int technology_skill_id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Empty Not Allow")]
        public string technology_skill_name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Empty Not Allow")]
        public string team_description { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Empty Not Allow")]
        public int leader_id { get; set; }


        public bool t1 { get; set; }

        public List<user_master> availableuser;
        public List<project_master> availableproject;
        public List<team_master> availableteam;
        public List<team_to_user> availableteamuser;

        public List<technology_skill_master> availabletechnology;

        public List<int> SelectSkill { get; set; }
        public List<int> lbtechnologyskillname2 { get; set; }

        public List<int> ddlModels { get; set; }
        public List<int> ddlModels1 { get; set; }

    }
}
```

2nd .cs file to fetch the data..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ProjectManagementSystem.Models
{
    public class TeamCreateFetch
    {
        private int counter = 1;


        //ProjectManagementSystemEntities3 pb = new ProjectManagementSystemEntities3();
        public static IList<TeamCreate> all()
        {     

            IList<TeamCreate> result =
                (IList<TeamCreate>)HttpContext.Current.Session["team1"];

            if (result == null)
            {
                ProjectManagementSystemEntities3 pb = new ProjectManagementSystemEntities3();

                HttpContext.Current.Session["team1"] = result =

                    ( from l in pb.team_master
                     join u in pb.user_master
                     on l.user_id equals u.user_id
                     select new TeamCreate
                     {
                         //SerialNumber= counter++,
                         team_id= l.team_id,
                         user_id = u.user_id,
                         team_name= l.team_name,
                         user_real_name=u.user_real_name,


            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

My database is as below...

**Table name - team_master**

```
team_id
team_name
user_id(FK with user_id of "user_master")
team_description
```

**Table-2 name- team_to _user**

```
user_id(PK)
user_real_name
```

**Table-3 name- team_to _user**

```
team_id (FK with team id of "team_master")
user_id (FK with user_id of "user_master")
```

Now i have to save the value of 2nd ListBox in the table "team_to _user" in user_id field.

**So how to do that in MVC-3??**

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest doing away with the dual list boxes and implement it as a single MultiSelectListBox.

The Model

```
public class MyClass {
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Items Selected (Use ctl + click to select multiple)")]
    public int[] SelectedItems { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ItemDTO> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ItemDTO { 
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The View

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedItems):                                                     
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedItems, new MultiSelectList(Model.Items, "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedItems))
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedItems)
```

In your controller, just loop thru the SelectedItems array and save each