# How to add rows dynamically at runtime in ASP.NET MVC using c#?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My model is:

```
public partial class transaction
{
    public int transaction_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> transaction_req_no { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> transaction_date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> transaction_reqst_by { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> transaction_priority { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> transaction_item { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> transaction_site { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> transaction_dept { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> transaction_reqst_status { get; set; }

    public virtual department department { get; set; }
    public virtual item item { get; set; }
    public virtual person person { get; set; }
    public virtual priority priority { get; set; }
    public virtual request request { get; set; }
    public virtual site site { get; set; }
    public virtual status status { get; set; }
}
```

The view:

```
 <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>transaction</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.transaction_req_no, "transaction_req_no", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("transaction_req_no", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.transaction_req_no, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.transaction_date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.transaction_date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.transaction_date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.transaction_reqst_by, "transaction_reqst_by", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("transaction_reqst_by", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.transaction_reqst_by, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.transaction_priority, "transaction_priority", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("transaction_priority", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.transaction_priority, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.transaction_item, "transaction_item", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.DropDownList("transaction_item", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.transaction_item, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>




        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.transaction_site, "transaction_site", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("transaction_site", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.transaction_site, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.transaction_dept, "transaction_dept", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("transaction_dept", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.transaction_dept, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.transaction_reqst_status, "transaction_reqst_status", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("transaction_reqst_status", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.transaction_reqst_status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

and controller is generated from scaffolding. No additional code is added there. i would like to add multiple transaction items. `public Nullable<int> transaction_item { get; set; }` The scaffolded view generates a drop down for this. I need a used to be able to add more than one items from front end.

[image: I would like to add this element dynamically.]

I read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/781851/Add-Delete-Rows-Dynamically-using-jQuery-in-ASP-NE), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28691404/how-to-add-new-row-dynamically-in-asp-net-mvc-5) and [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/145c93/adding-dynamic-rows-in-html-table-with-textboxes-and-with-de/). The [first](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/781851/Add-Delete-Rows-Dynamically-using-jQuery-in-ASP-NE) one looks promising but still i am not able to get how do i add data into database even if i can add elements in front end by using jQuery?

Comment: Thats my view generated by scaffolding.

Comment: The image you have shown is a form. The code you have show does not have a form or any form controls. Show the correct code.

Comment: I am very sorry. Just updated the correct code.

Comment: short answer Javascript.

Comment: see the answer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913905/asp-net-mvc-generate-post-forms/33914889#33914889

Comment: what i am thinking is to achieve this, add elements using jQuery in front end, then somehow keep track how many elements are added, this count will work as loop counter, the loop will add data into database...
I am not sure about this, either it is correct way or not...

Comment: If you want to select multiple `transaction_item`, then use `ListBoxFor()`, not `DropDownListFor()` which is for selecting a single item.

Comment: @AwaisMahmood how do i add the data in to database? Like the question you pointed, if i have 6 text boxes in front end, how do i get data in to database?

Comment: Do you want to select multiple instances of Transaction_item or pass multiple values?

Comment: @Vini i need multiple Transaction_items. i mean user can select many items and then in database i can see who selected what...

Comment: So basically in the database u want to store different values of transaction item for a user. Then as @StephenMuecke suggested you should use `ListBoxFor`.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28924335/5243291) answer should help.. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071927/how-to-save-the-value-of-listbox-in-the-database) can also help.

Answer (score 1):

Create it using `JQuery`, then use the `jquery prop InserAfter()` and add new row.

ex:

```
var r = $("HTML CODE");
$(r).insertAfter($("#BlaBlaBla"));
```

Comment: Like this ??
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/781851/Add-Delete-Rows-Dynamically-using-jQuery-in-ASP-NE

Comment: This works too, look at jquery page about insertAfter() function

Answer (score 1):

As far as frontend is related you can see [answer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913905/asp-net-mvc-generate-post-forms/33914889#33914889). You can use FormCollection instead of model directly. Then you can assign the values to your rows as :

> codelen1
>
> codelen2
>
> codelen3

then you can create a backend method to accept the formcollection as a parameter. In that method you can loop on the number of rows as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
publict ActionResult DynamicRows(FormCollection f)
{
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(f["level"]); // you will set the number of rows added from JQuery
    for (int a = 0; a <= i; a++)
    {
         ABC lvl = new ABC();
         lvl.S1 = a.ToString();
         lvl.N1 = a;
         lvl.N2 = Convert.ToInt32(f["codelen" + a.ToString()]); // here you are getting back the values as codelen1..codelen2..codelen3

         // your other logic comes here... anything you want to do with the data
         WebDb.ABC.Add(lvl);

    }
    WebDb.SaveChanges();
}
```